# App crashes when comparing two strings of type NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just just "isEqualToString:" to compare to strings in my iPhone App. The var value is a text and "subInput" is a string out of a text field. Till now everything went well, when the first character of the input field has been the same as the first character of the text. But when they don't fit, the App crashes. When typing in a wrong character after starting well, everything is ok.

```
subInput = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[theInput text]];
compare = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[value substringToIndex:subInput.length]];

if([subInput isEqualToString:compare]){
//Here the app stops working
```

I also tried to compare the result with "!= 0" or "!= nil" but also didn't work.

---

ADDITIONAL CODE

```
if([subInput isEqualToString:compare] != nil){
        NSLog(@"any");
        if([subInput isEqualToString:value]){
            NSLog(@"other");
            NSLog(@"well done");
            theInput.enabled = FALSE;
            lastValid = theInput.text;
            theMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            theMessage.text = @"WELL DONE!!!!";
            theMessage.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            //save points for remaining seconds
            score += seconds*10;
            //invalidate counter when typed in all text correct
            [count invalidate];
            [self newTimer:3.0];
        }else{

            if(theInput.text.length >= range){
                NSLog(@"SCROLLEN");
                [theText setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(range, addRange)];
                range += addRange;
            }
            //NSLog(@"String is ok");
            //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            lastValid = theInput.text;
            theMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            theMessage.text = @"GO GO GO";
            theMessage.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
        }

    } else{
        //incrementing the fail var for every wrong letter
        fails++;

        theInput.text = [@"" stringByAppendingString:lastValid];
        theMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        theMessage.text = @"WRONG CHARACTER!!!";
        theMessage.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        if (grade >= 2) {
            seconds -= 2;
        }

        if(grade == 3){
            int actual = theInput.text.length;
            actual--;
            NSString *shorterString = [theInput.text substringToIndex:actual];
            lastValid = shorterString;
            theInput.text = shorterString;

        }
        //change bg-color to iritate the player
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:[self r:255]/255.0 green:[self r:255]/255.0 blue:[self r:255]/255.0 alpha:1];
    }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Can we see some more code? In particular, the line at which you get the exception, and some code in the `if` statement.

Comment: I guess `[value substringToIndex:subInput.length]` is out of bounds. The initialization and comparison of the two strings seem to be fine.

Comment: isn't the variable `compare` null pointer?

Comment: no, thats why I don't understand, when the the two values are compared, i see both values inside the debugger or when hover over them. so their noch empty.

Comment: And I tried to type in the same value and it also crashes..
befor, I did the same With NSScanner but it crashed too, did it like that:
NSScanner *sub = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:theInput.text];
subInput = sub.string;
and after that I used it for defining the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to check that [theInput text] is NOT nil.

```
subInput = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[theInput text]];
```

Docs on [NSString initWithString:(NSString *)aString] are clear that you will get an exception if you attempt to initialize with a nil value.

Comment: thanks for this answer! :)
At this time I was still new to all this coding thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and see if value's length is greater than subInput's length. If it is not, you are going out of bounds there.